# How to get only the access token in this string?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

```
{"access_token":"OeB89uEWZZzLPLMIsVBvJtIlnObM1sX7NNNWqwtjdzI.8LlxO2skN028HmcMw8F_BDiqEj9kDRfdVWc9f02WmiY","expires_in":43199,"scope":"","token_type":"bearer"}
```

How to access only `access_token` from it like below:

```
$str = "OeB89uEWZZzLPLMIsVBvJtIlnObM1sX7NNNWqwtjdzI.8LlxO2skN028HmcMw8F_BDiqEj9kDRfdVWc9f02WmiY";
```

Comment: What do you mean access token extraction from this object or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_decode()`

```
<?php

$json = '{"access_token":"OeB89uEWZZzLPLMIsVBvJtIlnObM1sX7NNNWqwtjdzI.8LlxO2skN028HmcMw8F_BDiqEj9kDRfdVWc9f02WmiY","expires_in":43199,"scope":"","token_type":"bearer"}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($array['access_token']);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/MPuCn

Comment: @srinidhigururajan  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Go this way to get the token,

```
<?php

$t = '{"access_token":"OeB89uEWZZzLPLMIsVBvJtIlnObM1sX7NNNWqwtjdzI.8LlxO2skN028HmcMw8F_BDiqEj9kDRfdVWc9f02WmiY","expires_in":43199,"scope":"","token_type":"bearer"}';

$a = json_decode($t);

print_r($a->access_token);

?>
```

**Output**

```
OeB89uEWZZzLPLMIsVBvJtIlnObM1sX7NNNWqwtjdzI.8LlxO2skN028HmcMw8F_BDiqEj9kDRfdVWc9f02WmiY
```

Comment: If you find the answer usefull then please accept it.